# print UTF-8 values as it's original characters instead of their codes

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Look at this code:

```
a = {'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}
print a
```

As you can see I've filled 'name' and 'family' with UTF-8 characters. but when I print a, the result is:

```
{'name': u'\u0627\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0646', 'family': u'\u0634\u06cc\u0631\u0632\u0627\u062f\u06cc'}
```

How to force to print data like it stored in the variable?

Comment: What's printed *is* exactly what is stored in the variable. There's no way to distinguish between what's written as an escape sequence vs a literal at runtime unless you parse the source code. But if what you want is to never print escape sequences you can format the string yourself.

Comment: Well. You store the data as UNICODE, not UTF-8. To print it as a UTF-8 encoded string, you can use `print a['name'].encode('utf8')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert a `dict` to a `str` (as `print` does internally), it uses `repr` on the keys and values, so that the unicode codepoints are printed instead of the actual characters. You can fix this by printing the values individually, e.g.

```
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    print(u"{}: {}".format(key, value))
```

gives

```
name: احسان
family: شیرزادی
```

or - if you want the output to be the same format as `print a` - by using `join`:

```
print u"{" + ", ".join(u"{}: {}".format(key, value) for key, value in a.iteritems()) + "}"
```

gives

```
{name: احسان, family: شیرزادی}
```

**Note that this drops the quotes around strings** (which should be fine as long as you only use it for printing).

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
a = {'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}
for key in a:
    val = a[key].strip().encode('utf-8')
    print key, val
```

**OUTPUT**

```
name احسان
family شیرزادی
```